# Select - Setting a disabled selected option as well as having a bound *ngfor option

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-ngmodel

I have a piece of code that's not behaving the way I want it to.

Basically I want to have the "Please select a team" value to come up as the default selected option so I don't have to have a visible label assigned to the dropdown (I hope that makes sense).

The code works ok in so much as the team values appear and the "Please select a Team" appears, however the drop down selects the first element of the *ngfor option not the "Please select a Team" option

Can anybody shed some light on this please?  I'm pretty new to Angular so be gentle.

```
<label for="team" class="sr-only">Team </label>
  <select [(ngModel)]="model" autocomplete="off" required>
      <option value="default" disabled selected>Please select a 
Team</option>
      <option *ngFor="let team of teams" [value]="team.name"> {{team.name}}</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Angular's data binding for the value attribute. Change `value="default"` to `[value]="default"`. Also be sure to read [this](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-syntax-an-overview) Angular doc to learn more about data binding

Take a look at [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hwrkpm) and let me know if this is your expected result

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for this.  When I ran your stckblitz it worked fine, however I just cut and paste your html code into mine and I still get the same behaviour.  `<label for="team" class="sr-only">Team </label>
      <select [(ngModel)]="model" autocomplete="off" required>
          <option [value]="default">Please select a Team</option>
          <option *ngFor="let team of teams" [value]="team.name">{{team.name}}</option>
      </select>`

Comment: Could it be something to do with the service that the component is interacting with?  In your code you have `teams = [{name: "Team A"}, {name: "Team B"}];` to create your teams.  Mine is getting them from an underlying service

Comment: @Taff Try adding [selected]="teams" although I am not sure why it isn't working for you.

Answer (score 0):

`disabled` cannot be `selected` at the same time. Choose one.

Comment: Sorry, I took out disabled as per your suggestion, however it still does not select it as the default option.